# I have a function which scores my data as 1 or 0(right or wrong) for MCQ responses(A,B,C,D). I want NA to be scored as NA not as 0

Tags: r

I have a column called 'KEY' which stores the correct response for each MCQ question. I also have the data set which contains scored responses such as A,B,C,D. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip9Ou.jpg)(notice how it has some responses which are NA or --) is how my data looks like. This is how my [Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmb1u.jpg) looks like.

I am using [this function](https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt/blob/master/R/key2binary.R) to score the data:-

```
  key2binary <- function (fulldata, key, score_missing = FALSE){
    if(missing(fulldata)) missingMsg('fulldata')
    if(missing(key)) missingMsg('key')
    if(is.vector(key)) key <- matrix(key)
    if (ncol(fulldata) != nrow(key)) stop("Key is not the correct length.\n", call.=FALSE)
    colname <- colnames(fulldata)
    X <- matrix(0L, nrow(fulldata), ncol(fulldata))
    colnames(X) <- colname
    for(i in 1L:ncol(X)){
      if(all(is.na(key[i,]))) next
      X[,i] <- fulldata[,i] %in% key[i,] + 0L
    }
    if(!score_missing)
      X[is.na(fulldata)] <- NA
    X
  }
```

The issue is that it also scores responses which are NA as 0. I want responses which are NA to be scored as NA only.

```
resp <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(
  "B","B","NA","D","E",
  "B","A","D","NA","E",
  "B","A","D","C","E",
  "D","D","D","C","E",
  "B","C","A","D","A"), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE))

key <- c("B", "D", "D", "C", "E")

key2binary(resp, key)
```

This returns NA as 0 . But i want NA to be returned as NA

Comment: Please supply a sample of your input data using `dput()` or `dput(head())`.  Looking at your code, I think your life would be easier if your data were [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  Where is `missingMsg` defined?

Comment: https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt/blob/master/R/key2binary.R 
i had taken the function from here. I forgot to link it. I will update the data using dput asap

Comment: I have edited the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `NA` values as strings ('NA') and not actual `NA`'s. It should work once you convert it to actual `NA` values.

```
resp[resp == 'NA'] <- NA
key2binary(resp, key)

#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#[1,]  1  0 NA  0  1
#[2,]  1  0  1 NA  1
#[3,]  1  0  1  1  1
#[4,]  0  1  1  1  1
#[5,]  1  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: This worked! However i ultimately wanted to run it in Shiny app. I had a clean_data() as eventReactive and the key which i had selected from a specifc coloumn. It shows 'argument of length 0' , i have no idea why. 
output$scoredData <- renderDataTable({
  cf<- control();
  resp<-data.frame(clean_data())
  key2binary(resp[resp == 'NA'] <- NA,(cf[cf$IsScorable == TRUE,c('ScoringKey')]),score_missing=FALSE)
})

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in a single line

```
key2binary(resp, key) * NA^(resp == 'NA')
```

-output

```
      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
[1,]  1  0 NA  0  1
[2,]  1  0  1 NA  1
[3,]  1  0  1  1  1
[4,]  0  1  1  1  1
[5,]  1  0  0  0  0
```